# Unable to install PMD in eclipse!

Tags: java

We use eclise 3.2.1. While trying to install PMD with the instructions given in http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/pmd/#howtouse, i am getting the following error and could not able to install it.

"Network connection problems encounterd during search".

But the internet is working fine..what could be the problem? Please suggest some alternatvies..

Thank u,
Best Regards,
Santhi

Comment: Proxy settings? Why do you use such an old version?

Answer (score 0):

You will find more information in the error log of Eclipse. Look there and post the full error message (if it doesn't already tell you what is wrong). Most likely, there is something wrong with your proxy settings or you still have playboy.com in the mirror list or something like that.

Also, consider to upgrade to the latest version of Eclipse. The step from 3.2 to 3.3 was a bit painful (many plugins didn't work) but that has been fixed long ago.

Comment: Hi Aaron,

This is the exact error..
Network connection problems encountered during search.
  Unable to access "http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/".
    Unable to access site: "http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/" [Connection timed out: connect]
    Unable to access site: "http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/" [Connection timed out: connect]

Comment: What happens when you open `http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/site.xml` in a browser?